# How to achieve variability in a microservice architecture?

Tags: microservices, code-duplication

Say i had an application consisting of a few microservices.
The application was used to maintain football matches (players, teams, matches, ...).

Now instead of just supporting football matches, i want my application to also handle basketball matches. ~90% of the functionality would be the same, but there were some minor differences.

What would be the best approach to achieve this variability?

I could

1. extend the existing microservices to support football as well as basketball matches. However if i were to add other sports in the future, the service would get more and more complex accounting for sport-specific details.
2. make the service implementation highly configurable and deploy multiple instances of my services with different configurations for soccer and basketball matches.
3. duplicate all code of my existing services and make some minor changes that account for the basketball specific things. However if i added other sports, i would end up maintaining lots of projects that share 90% of their codebase.

What would be the cleanest way to achieve some variability in a microservice architecture and be able to easily add different sports in the future with only minor sport-specific implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language and/or framework your microservices are written in, you may be able to factor out the 90% of the codebase which is common (e.g. that which defines common endpoints etc.) into a library and then each service becomes the 10% that differs and a (likely) small amount of glue code to link the 10% with the 90%.

It might also make sense to factor out the common things (e.g. that games have a scheduled start time) into their own service.

Comment: Wouldnt a shared library be against the "shared nothing" principle because it creates a rather tight coupling between the microservices, since they aren't really isolated anymore?

Comment: Not really, or at least it's no more coupling than if you duplicated functionality.  There's zero coupling in execution (which is the most important decoupling), unless you really implement the library poorly (e.g. avoiding dependency injection if the functionality requires DB access).  In terms of development coupling, if different services discover that they need incompatible functionality from the library, at least one of them can fork the library etc.

Comment: Would you say that two services which both happen to be implemented in Node are tightly coupled or not really isolated any more?

Comment: Well, i wouldnt say that those 2 Node services aren't isolated.

In case of a shared library tho, i would say, that changes on the library affect all microservices which creates some coupling or atleast reduces the independency of each service. I guess in those cases i could fork the library then like you suggested, which would ultimately be a code duplication again.

Comment: There's also no obligation for services using a library to upgrade unless they need to, which unless there's some coupling elsewhere, is purely driven by what those services need (again, there's no intrinsic reason a new Node version coming out means every service you implemented in Node needs to be upgraded).

Comment: Does the fact that every service you implement almost certainly shares a dependency on the C standard library make them less independent?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?